# jQuery UI Spinner + Custom Theme - Buttons Under Input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I am trying to apply a theme-roller theme to a page with jquery-ui spinners. Once the theme is applied the buttons for the spinner are mostly hidden under the input.

Here is the entire page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $(".spinner").spinner().width(120);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="spin" class="spinner" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

(Apologies for not using jfiddle. You have to download the theme to see the problem.) I didn't change the theme in any way. There is an [example of the spinner working with the theme here](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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). You can also download the theme from that page.

I have found a few cases of people complaining about the same problem but no solution. I tried different versions of jquery (3, 2 & 1). You can remove the .width(120) and the type="text" from the element. The [example jquery provides](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/) doesn't use those.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1g1yaL2x/

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is based on your description. Do you see any errors in console or when you inspect the elements.

Comment: There are no errors. The arrows for the spinner are mostly obscured by the input box.